Free appears to be corrupting buffer values
Ok, I know reading a buffer after free'ing it is wrong. I was trying to prove a point that free() does not touch the data stored in the buffer, but I am unable to prove it :)
Here is the code:
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p = malloc(3);
    char *s = p;

    memcpy(p, "aaa", 3);
    free(p);

    printf(" s = ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

Output:
% ./a.out
 s = 0?I-E3?

Every time I run it, the output is different.
Is there an explanation for what I see? Do modern malloc libraries sneak in some security functionality in? This is on a Mac if that matters.
I expect to see aaa how ever I see 0?I-E3?

Reading from the buffer after it was freed is invoking undefined behavior.

Undefined behaviour by reading the buffer after it was freed and no one ever said that free() does not touch the buffer

Not saying it is a good idea, but if I were to try this, I would not use printf() and would only try to print the 3 chars that were in the buffer, not past the end of the former buffer. And there is no guarantee that free doesn't alter the memory of the former buffer. I can imagine 2 reasons why an implementation might do so. It doesn't mater if it does as long as you code properly and do not touch it after free().

You try to access ten bytes of the three you allocate. Going out of bounds is invalid and leads to undefined behavior. Just like using memory that is not allocated to your process.

fyi. that you even receive an output is "pure luck". in the worst case your program crashes

Fwiw, this is how I might revise your code with undefined behavior . It appears that this implementation's free() may overwrite part of the buffer. Possibly for internal bookkeeping.

What is undefined behavior and how does it work? Also you need to learn about strings, you didn't allocate enough room to store the string "aaa" including null terminator.

I think they are aware that it is an undefined behaviour (in some loose way). I interpret this question as an attempt from yyyyy to develop an intuition of what is happening under the hood of free. It's a fair guess to assume that free would only impact some registry of allocated memory segment and not the data itself and then subsequently finding counter intuitive that the data systematically change after a free. Why is that undefined behavior consistent in changing the data.

I don't get how this can get 5 upvotes. OP knows this is undefined behavior. Yet OP ask about the behavior. Like "The standard does not define the result, so why don't I get this specific result". Makes no sense. Yet 5 upvotes. Makes no sense.

I was trying to prove a point that free() does not touch the data stored in the buffer, but I am unable to prove it  And what was that belief based on?  Even if your one call to free() didn't change the buffer contents, another thread could allocate that memory and update it immediately.

This question is similar to: Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The reason for closing this question is incorrect.  The OP is mistaken and so might be a number of other programmers, not necessarily beginners.  This deserves a clear answer to Is there an explanation for what I see?.  At least 4 other voters seem to think this way, so I propose to reopen this question.

You cannot prove that "free() does not touch the data stored in the buffer" for multiple reasons.  Mainly because the standard imposes no such requirement on implementations.  (A really good free() will make the memory inaccessible, and cause your program to dump core when you perform the invalid access).


Ok, I know reading a buffer after free'ing it is wrong.

Indeed it has undefined behavior, anything can happen including what you are trying to prove but also anything else including different output each time or a segmentation fault.

I was trying to prove a point that free() does not touch the data stored in the buffer, but I am unable to prove it :)

There is no point trying to prove this as the C Standard does not provide any guarantees whatsoever of this sort: on the contrary, it does specify that the behavior is undefined.
Some implementations might not change some or all of the freed memory area, which might have mislead you to believe this to be expected, but others may store ancillary data there or even fill the area with random bytes to try and make undefined behavior more obvious.
Be aware that the memory area may even be unmapped and accessing it could cause abrupt program termination.  Accessing memory in a freed block is just not something any program should attempt.
Furthermore, note that you are accessing 10 bytes where you only allocated 3, which would have undefined behavior even before freeing the block.

@yyyyy: you can accept this or another answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Yes. First of all, you read characters beyond the allocated space and there is no reason to assume that the information there will be the same each time you test.
BUT
Assuming that you would loop only to the amount you allocated, even then, freeing the resource basically releases control over it and therefore there will be no guarantee subsequently that it will continue to store your data.

One explanation for this is:

When you free memory, the memory management software uses some of the freed memory to link it into data structures the software uses to manage blocks of memory available for allocation.
When the program is loaded, memory layout is deliberately randomized to foil some exploit attacks. So addresses will vary from run to run, including pointers used by the memory management software.

There can be other explanations.

RAM is also in a chaotic state when powered up. If no software explicitly writes zero to it, then the values will be pretty much random.
